# Prove that the group G defined by a~b=a+b+ab is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers.

Tags: group-theory, graph-isomorphism

Question: Prove that the group $G$ consisting of the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}$ with multiplication defined by $a\sim b=a+b+ab$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers, $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}, \times)$.

I'm trying to find a function that equates the two groups. Let's call the isomorphism Y. I've tricked around with $Y(a\sim b)=(ab+a+b)-(a+b)$, but this is taking in two input variables, so when it comes to trying to show $Y(a\sim b)=Y(a)(b)$, the function loses all of its meaning. So then I tried $Y(a)=-a$, but then $Y(a\sim b)=-a-b-ab \neq Y(a)y(b) = ab$.

A little help here? It's probably something obvious, but I'm having difficulties at forming a legitimate map.

Comment: What happens if you add the identity element and attempt to factor?

Comment: What set do the group elements belong to? Because something seems wrong...the identity element is $0$ as $0\sim b = b$ for all $b$. However $-1$ then has no inverse, as $-1 \sim b = -1$ for all $b$.

Comment: whoops, forgot to mention that the group G is defined on the set R\{-1}

Comment: That's kind of important, Mik. You have to edit your question, I'm afraid.

Comment: @TonyK We are all allowed to edit questions you know...

Comment: @user1729: I wanted Mik to realise that just posting a comment was not an appropriate response.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Consider the isomorphism function

> $Y(a)=a+e$

where $e$ is the multiplicative identity.  Then we have

> $Y(a\text ~ b)=ab+a+b+e=(a+e)(b+e)$

Taking $e=1$ for the set $\Bbb R\setminus\{-1\}$, we see that we would have $Y(-1)=-1+1=0$, and $Y(-1\text~b)=Y(a\text~-1)=0$ if we allowed $-1$ to be part of the set.

Answer (score 2):

A hint:

Note that $a+b+ab=(a+1)\cdot(b+1)-1$ and therefore
$$(a\odot b)+1=(a+1)\cdot(b+1)\ .$$